# email activity - any solution to being able to preview like print/merge document?

Tags: email, civicase, activity

When using the single email activity (not civimail) is there a way of previewing the email - with the tokens replaced - like in print/merge document?

I had a quick fiddle with coding a button for it, but the handling of the email activity seems to be quite a bit different to the regular forms.  Doesn't seem to use the post form hook for example.

I have the same issue on both contact and case email activities

Answer (score 0):

There isn't such a feature currently.

This is related, but not exactly the same as what you're asking, but if implemented might help facilitate a preview: https://lab.civicrm.org/dev/core/-/issues/1750

Comment: Thanks, similar agreed.   This is another really odd design decision to me.  Surely you want the "actual" email, with the correct data at the time of the email stored.

But the lack of the preview - especially when it is present in the print/merge is irritating.